# Alternate Access Mapping URL requires login

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, login

I have a problem with an Alternate Access Mapping URL.

When I access my site collection through:

```
http://myserver:8005
```

it works fine (user is automatically recognized).

But when I access it through an AAM url

```
http://myintranet.domain:8005
```

I need to type in username and password domain

Do you know what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to add the AAM url into Trusted zone?

Comment: Do you mean in the browser? I have tried now and doesn't work. Though  I was looking for something that didn't require changing the browser preferences.

Comment: Actually I see that in IE, Local Intranet sites weren't set to be detected automatically. With automatic detection it works, so you have a point

Comment: can you mark it as answer, if you like the point...:)

Comment: I think you need to put it as an answer.I don't think I can mark a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add it in the Trusted Zone. as you said "Local Intranet sites weren't set to be detected automatically. With automatic detection it works,"